# how to create a table with two primary keys where one is foreign key in one table and the other on another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two primary keys. municipality tables has two entities: municipality_code and municipality_names both primary keys. there is one table postcode which has municipality_code as a foreign key. on the other hand there is another table which has municipality_name as a foreign key. How can I connect them?

Comment: There can't be two primary keys on a table. There can be a single primary key that encompasses two columns. Please include the table definition in your question e.g in `psql` \dt the_table_name

Comment: A table cannot have *two* primary keys.  A table can have multiple *candidate* primary keys.  A table can have a composite primary key.  But a table cannot have two primary keys.  Only one is primary.

Comment: understand. how can I connect three tables like in the scenario described above?

Comment: @Michael27 you make a composite primary key on ( municipality_code , municipality_names) and you make two foreign key on each of the columns referred to respective table

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one primary key. But a `UNIQUE NOT NULL` constraint is just as good as a primary key and can serve as target of a foreign key constraint.

While that solves your immediare problem, I'd suggest that you change the data model so that you always use the same column as target of foreign keys. It makes your data model more understandable.

Comment: I understand what you mean. but the tables is how I have been given so the idea is how i am manage them. that's the problem. I don't have the right to change the data model.

Comment: Well, at least you need a unique constraint, otherwise you cannot have a foreign key. You'll have to invoke the powers that can change the schema.